# OP amp noise density and Johnson noise (Thermal noise) for 16bits ADC

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, noise-spectral-density

I am trying to create a analogique amplification chain between a piezo sensor (10mVPP) and 16 bits ADC in 3V3 range. I try to simulate the chain on LTSpice to get the lower noise density I can get.
@3V3 for 16bits  3.3/2^16  = **50.35 µVRMS** for 1 LSB.

When I simulate the noise on a nominalistic chain I quickly go over the ADC LSB only with thermal noise.
I think I misunderstand my result.
In this exemple I just put an OPAMP with gain x400 and two filter HP 1.5 kHz and LP 50 kHz and I already go **523 µVRMS** that is 10 times the LSB of the ADC... (This use 4 bits of my ADC just for thermal noise)

Can someone help me to clarify this ?
(I know it's just a simulation and not real life, but I don't understand why I can't go down to 1 LSB on 16 bits on simulation)

**Schematic**
[image: Schematic]
**Noise analysis**
[image: Noise]
**Signals**
[image: Signal]
**Response**
[image: Transfer function]

Comment: What is the ultrasound bandwidth of interest? If it is small, you can use a bandpass digital filter to remove noise where you know there will be no signal.

Comment: @bobflux Yes but I want to do maximum analog filtering to don't load ADC dynamic in unused frequency range and dont overload my MCU. This is for industrial vibrating control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Can someone help me to clarify this ?*

**Input voltage noise of the op-amp**

Your op-amp has an input noise voltage of typically 1.1 \$\text{nV/}\sqrt{Hz}\$. Your noise bandwidth is 50 kHz x 1.57 (for a simple RC low pass filter). Hence the equivalent noise at your input is: -

$$1.1 \text{nV} \times \sqrt{50,000 \times 1.57} = 308 \text{ nV RMS}$$

Multiply this by the circuit gain (400) and the output noise is **123 μV RMS**.

**Input current noise of the op-amp**

The op-amp also has an input current noise of typically 2.4 \$\text{pA/}\sqrt{Hz}\$. Your input circuit isn't balanced so that produces an equivalent voltage noise source into R2 of 2.4 \$\text{nV/}\sqrt{Hz}\$. Using the same math as above and multiplying by the gain (400) yields an output noise of **268 μV RMS**.

**Combining the noises**

Adding the two noises together (using Pythagoras) means a combined noise of **295 μV RMS**.

I haven't tried to calculate thermal noises from resistors nor the low frequency noise of the op-amp because my numbers look close enough to your LTSpice calculation.

Personally, I'd reduce the 400 k and the 1 k feedback resistors to one tenth their value and eradicate the major contributor (the input current noise).

> *I don't understand why I can't go down to 1 LSB on 16 bits on
> simulation*

Do you understand now?

Comment: Many thanks Andy, really clear and understandable, this clarify a lot of thing I read on the web or datasheet like input source resistor, equivalent resistor, en ,in, etc.... With 40k & 100 ohms feedback I got output noise  down to 182µVRMS. Too much for 16bits but in good way (/3 factor amelioration).  I really wonder if I can compare 1 LSB voltage to RMS noise density voltage. So I need to rethink all my amplifying and filtering chain. Thanks to take time for helping.

Comment: In reality, 1 lsb of rms noise actually means that 99.9 % of the time the peak to peak signal will be limited to a noise span of 6.6 lsbs. Go search for converting rms noise to peak to peak for better insight on Gaussian noise. This makes things much worse in reality. Sorry to disappoint.

Comment: Ok :(, I take look on Gaussian distribution and where de 8 (6.6 LSB) came into account.
It's usual to have filter/amp chain to 16 bits ADC with the 4/6 least significant bit "wriggling" when input is shorted to ground ?

Comment: @rom1nux it's not unusual to have noise on a few bits of the ADC and, in many, many situations, it is unavoidable.